# Is it safe to put your email address in an npm module's package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, metadata

Documentation for reference:
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Couldn't a bot/program harvest people's emails from package.json files and send them spam etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there's nothing stopping someone from scraping node modules for the author's email address. That being said, there are countless other sites where your email is also vulnerable to spam.

I wouldn't consider the potential for spam to be more problematic than a consumer not having the contact information of the package author.